# How to detect that a vector is subset of specific vector?

Tags: r, vector, set, subset

I have two vectors (sets) like this:

```
first<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
second<-c(2,4,5)
```

how can I detect that whether `second` is subset of `first` or not? is there any function for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way

```
> all(second %in% first)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another

```
setequal(intersect(first, second), second)
## [1] TRUE
```

Or

```
all(is.element(second, first))
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score -2):

If the order of the array elements matters, string conversion could help:

```
ord_match <- function(x,y){
    m <- c(0,grep(paste0(x,collapse=""),
                  paste0(y,collapse=""), fixed = T))
    return(as.logical(m)[length(m)])
}
```