# User defined function checking whether two column names exists in a data frame showing incorrect output

Tags: r, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I am creating a user defined function that checks for whether the two column names that a user supplies into the function exists in a given data frame. There are three outcomes for the function: (1) both column names do not exist in the data frame; (2) var1 does not exist in the data frame, but var2 does; and (3) var2 does not exist in the data frame, but var1 does.

The function is as follows:

```
vars_check <- function(df, var1, var2) {
  
  if (!all(c(var1, var2) %in% names(df))) {
    stop(paste("Both", var1, "and", var2, 
                "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  }
  
  if (!var1 %in% names(df)) {
    stop(paste(var1, "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  } 
  
  if (!var2 %in% names(df)) {
    stop(paste(var2, "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  }
}
```

Using the iris dataset as an example, I got the following incorrect output when var1 does not exist in the data frame, but var2 does:

```
vars_check(iris, "dslmfbndsfb", "Species")
Error in vars_check(iris, "dslmfbndsfb", "Species") : 
  Both dslmfbndsfb and Species cannot be found in the dataset
```

The issue is "Species" exists in the data frame, and the function should provide me with outcome 2 (var1 doesn't exist; var2 exists) instead of outcome 1 (both do not exist). When I put in a non-existent column for var2 and an existing column for var1, the incorrect output is shown.

I have tried to modify my code such that the initial `if` is followed by two more `else if`, but some way or another, I get an incorrect output for one of the permutations.

I have based my function on the idea that is found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831041/how-to-detect-that-a-vector-is-subset-of-specific-vector).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all(c(var1, var2) %in% names(df))` is already `FALSE` if either `var1` or `var2` is missing, with the negation `!` this condition is `TRUE` if only one of the variables is missing. You can explicitly check:

```
vars_check <- function(df, var1, var2) {
  
  if (!var1 %in% names(df) && !var2 %in% names(df)) {
    stop(paste("Both", var1, "and", var2, 
               "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  }
  
  if (!var1 %in% names(df)) {
    stop(paste(var1, "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  } 
  
  if (!var2 %in% names(df)) {
    stop(paste(var2, "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `any`:

```
vars_check <- function(df, var1, var2) {
  
  if (!any(c(var1, var2) %in% names(df))) {
    stop(paste("Both", var1, "and", var2, 
               "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  }
  
  if (!var1 %in% names(df)) {
    stop(paste(var1, "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  } 
  
  if (!var2 %in% names(df)) {
    stop(paste(var2, "cannot be found in the dataset"))
  }
}
```

I think the correct keyword here is the De Morgan's laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws